# how read a stream from textarea?

Tags: java, awt

hi i have this simple code that reads a line from console, now i want to read this line from a textarea just like console ( by pressing enter the line should be read ) what should i do ?

```
 private DataInputStream  co   = null;
   private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;


 public void run()
   {  while (thread != null)
      {  try
         {   
             streamOut.writeUTF(co.readLine());

            streamOut.flush();
         }
         catch(IOException ioe)
         {  System.out.println("Sending error: " + ioe.getMessage());
            stop();
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: This would probably be better suited to using a `JTextField`.  Add an `ActionListener` to determine when the user presses `Enter`.  BTW - the tag states AWT but this millennium we should use Swing.  DYM a `java.awt.TextArea` or a `javax.swing.JTextArea`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach KeyListener to your textarea, wait until enter will be pressed then get textarea's text, split it by line breaks and get last line.

Or, you can make your KeyListener append each key pressed into StringBuilder and reset builder every time user press enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
            String[] data = txtarea.getText().split("\\n");

            for(int i = 0 ; i< data.length; i++)
                System.out.println(data[i]);
```

Above given line read from Jtextarea and write those content on to console...